# UITextView inside UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextview

I know this question has been asked before, though I can't seem to find what I want.  I have a section in my app where I have a tableview with a textview inside of it.  I DO NOT want to have a seperate .xib, .h, and .m files for the tableview cell. The tableview does not need to shrink or grow depending on the amount of text inside the textview.  I don't want the textview to be editable either.  I hope this isn't too much to ask for, though I'm really stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To do this, you will need to embed one in your UITableViewCell.  But there's no need to create a custom cell.  Here is the basic idea of what you will want to do:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UITextView *comment = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, tableView.rowHeight)];
        comment.editable = NO;
        comment.delegate = self;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:comment];
        [comment release];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

You will, of course, need to set your rowHeight if you don't want the standard 44pt height that comes with the cell.  And if you want actual cells, you'll need to add your own logic so that only the cell you want is a textView, but this is the basic idea.  The rest is yours to customize to your fitting.  Hope this helps

EDIT: to bypass the textView to get to your cell, there are two ways to go about this.

1) you can make a custom textView class and overwrite touchesBegan to send the message to super:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

this will send the touch events to its superview, which would be your tableView.  Considering you didn't want to make custom UITableViewCells, I imagine you probably don't want to make a custom textView class either.  Which leads me to option two.

2) when creating the textView, remove `comment.editable = NO;`.  We need to keep it editable, but will fix that in a delegate method.

In your code, you will want to insert a textView delegate method and we'll do all our work from there:

EDIT: changing this code to use with a UITableViewController

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
// this method is called every time you touch in the textView, provided it's editable;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:textView.superview.superview];
    // i know that looks a bit obscure, but calling superview the first time finds the contentView of your cell;
    //  calling it the second time returns the cell it's held in, which we can retrieve an index path from;

    // this is the edited part;
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    // this programmatically selects the cell you've called behind the textView;


    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // this selects the cell under the textView;
    return NO;  // specifies you don't want to edit the textView;
}
```

If that's not what you wanted, just let me know and we'll get you sorted out

Comment: Won't this always add a subview when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called? Shouldn't the UITextView be added inside the if(cell == nil) condition block?

Comment: This will add one every time, yes.  It would be a better idea to add it in the if(cell == nil) block.  I apologize for that.  I use this in a case form in one of my apps and I set my cells to nil every time it's called to update where the cells are and provide new tags.  I thought I remembered to modify it back to normal for you, but missed that part, so I'm glad you caught it.  I'll edit that to its correct spot now

Comment: Haha I'm guilty of that same thing as well :) Learnt the hard way when my tableview scrolled like a snail and I couldn't figure out why... cheers!

Comment: It's always the little things that get you, haha.  Thanks again for the good catch, though.  I definitely appreciate it

Comment: @slev sorry to ask another question, but when I tap on the table view cell, the text view is in the way and won't register the tap.  I'm sure there is an obvious solution, though how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Ok, this is a bit of a work around, but it should do what you want.  I'm going to edit the original answer because it'll be easier to type it out there instead of in a comment

Comment: @slev This works, though I had to tweak the code a bit to get it working, and now I have an error.  The problem is that the view I need to place the textView in is a TableViewController (which makes things difficult). I get the error on the NSIndexPath line because I had to change myTableView to self.tableview.  How would I fix this?

Comment: Alright.  I just tested this out on a UITableViewController just to make sure there's no problem, and it works like a charm.  I'll change it in the original answer so it's easier

Comment: @slev (Sorry, I ask way too many questions) This worked, though I get a warning: Incompatible pointer types sending "UIView *" to parameter type 'UITableViewCell *' What's up with this? Also, this is just me being extremely picky, but is there a way to make the textView have a clear background (When the textView is touched, the cell doesn't light up blue)?

Comment: No worries, I don't mind the questions at all.  I get that warning too.  It's not a big deal.  Since you're looking at superviews, it's expecting them to be UIView instances, but if you use an NSLog statement, it clearly shows it's a UITableViewCell instance in this case.  I wish I knew how to get rid of the warning, but it's not harmful at all.  So no worries there.  As for making a clear background, when creating the textView, just tell it `comment.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` and you should be fine

Comment: @slev Thanks for the fast reply, though that didn't seem to solve my problem.  When I tap on the textView to advance to the next view, the navigation controller is pushed, though the cell doesn't light up blue.  However, when I tap on the cell but not on the textView, the cell does light up.  Also, is there any way I can give you a reputation boost for answering all of my questions?

Comment: Sorry this is taking forever.  I've been looking everywhere to try and figure out why it's not highlighting.  I've tried telling the cell to highlight, but it won't, as well as calling any and all methods that _should_ set it to a highlighted state, but nothing works so far.  I'm going to keep looking and hopefully have something for you soon.  And as far as boosting reputation, I don't think there's anything you can do in here for that.  I suppose if I add more answers for the different questions and let you vote them up, it would work, but that's up to you.  I'm just glad to help out

Comment: Ok, I got it.  I apparently had it a long time ago, but forgot to remove my `comment.editable = NO;` this whole time.  Oops.  Anyway, I'll edit the original with the correct way to go about it

Comment: @slev Finally! I got everything working perfectly, so this is just me thanking you again :)

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad it all works, and you're more than welcome =]