# UITextView in custom UITableViewCell not responding to didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my custom UITableViewCell and the issue is that when I tap on it it won't respond to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath or even swipe events. How can I fix this? This UITextView is not editable. The reason why I use this over a UITextField is because I want to be able to detect links easily.

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is an old question, but I recently had the same issue. The fix in my case was to simply turn off "User Interaction Enabled" for the UITextView.

Answer (score 2):

you need to forward the touch messages from UITableView to UITextView

[UITextView inside UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997708/uitextview-inside-uitableview)

Comment: well then you're saying the whole cell has to be a UITextView?

Answer (score 0):

The first idea that came to mind...

In cellForRow set the textfield tag as the indexpath.row

Implement `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

Based on this textView.tag, call the selectrow

```
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textView.tag inSection:<#(NSUInteger)#>] 
animated:<#(BOOL)#> scrollPosition:<#(UITableViewScrollPosition)#>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what are you looking for But in my case i had a custom cell with UIImage, and UITextView and only when I clicked on UIImageView i got didSelectRowAtIndexPath recogniser. Make sure UITextView is user interections unable like that to fix the problem

Answer (score -2):

Check if your TableView Selection property is set to NO

Wrong :
tableView.allowsSelection = false

*DidSelect Wont be called*
It has to be: 
tableView.allowsSelection = true

Also [Check your Nib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXc08.png)