# UiTextView in Custom UiTableViewCell does not responds to didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITextView` on a custom `UITableViewCell` and when I click on the `UITextView`, it does not trigger the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, how do I change this behavior so that that delegate is called as intended?

Ive tried putting the User enabled property of `UITextView` to false. When doing so it responds to the didSelect. But then Im not able to select the links that are mentioned in the TextView, which essentially is the main reason why i chose to go ahead with `UITextView`.

Any help or pointer guys

Comment: You can't touch `superView` if `subView` absorve all the touch you have made. And `cell` touch is responsible for triggering `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` not the `textView`.

Comment: Yup!! you are right mate!! I can notice that whenever i click on cell anywhere outside the boundary of `textView`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is responding. But im sure there must be a way to achieve the desired effect. Somehow passing the touches from `subview` to `superview`?? or is it not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView in custom UITableViewCell not responding to didSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065404/uitextview-in-custom-uitableviewcell-not-responding-to-didselectrowatindexpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to work around by putting a custom `UIButton` on `UITableCellView` and firing off the required methods on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. This ate my brains for 2 days!!

Answer (score 0):

you can't do both the things at same time.

you can use `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` in you didselectrowatindexpath method.

you need to give appropriate tag to every text field and by using `[cell viewWithTag:<#(NSInteger)#>]` you can get the text-field object and link  which are mentioned in it .

Comment: Hmmm interesting concept SmartWork!! what if my table view cell itself is custom and UITextView is defined on that?

Comment: than it will become more easy for you, you just need to write cell.yourtextfieldname to get text field obj.

Answer (score 0):

If your table view is custom, you can fire didSelectRowAtIndexPath event yourself when the user touch the text view.