# Enable Edit Mode in ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard, xcode4.5

I'm new on iOS development, i m trying to show a user profile inside a view, and in the same time i want to give a user a possibility to edit his profile by tapping an "Edit" button on the UINavigationBar like shown on Apple web site : [Enabling Edit Mode in a View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/EnablingEditModeinaViewController/EnablingEditModeinaViewController.html)

I tried to find a tutorial explaining all this, but i didn't fin anything. can somebody help me plz, by giving me a link for a tutorial, or a sample code ?

PS : I m using storyboard.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://behindtechlines.com/2012/06/enabling-configuring-uitableview-edit-mode/) and [here](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-ios-programming-alasdair-allan-2nd/chapter-5/edit-mode) are a couple of examples for a UITableview

The concept is the same. You add a UIBarButtonItem and change the current mode of the tableView and the status(text) of the buttonItem to show the editing dashes and other content if you choose.

Here is a simple edit mode button press to send the tableView into edit mode to allow for easy deleting. You can also

```
- (IBAction)editPressed:(id)sender
{
    // If the tableView is editing, change the barButton title to Edit and change the style
    if (_theTableView.isEditing) {
        UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(editPressed:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton;
        _buttonEdit = newButton;
        [_theTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
    // Else change it to Done style
    else {
        UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editPressed:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton;
        _buttonEdit = newButton;
        [_theTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
}


-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // You could do other things in here based on whether editing is true or not
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the problem is that i m a beginner on iOS, the examples are not so clear for me ! i m trying to understand them and to apply them, i'll keep you informed if i can do it.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions plz !

Comment: You need to specify what you are wanting to do and ask specific questions or you won't get a whole lot of help around here. This is a community built around extremely quick and reliable responses but ONLY if the question is very specific and previously not asked. Google is your friend, you can find a ton of resources on enabling edit mode.

Comment: you are right, maybe my question is not clear ! i tried google, but i didn't find anything :(
Assuming that i have 1 field (Name) on UITableView, when i click on "Edit" Button, i want the TabViewCell to became a UITextView to let me edit the data. And then whem i click the "Done" Button the UITextView became a TabViewCell again with new Value ! 
Is that possible ?
All i can found as tutorial, is just how to delete, add or move a cell.
I'll be grateful if you can help me, and if you think that this is not clear enough i can reformulate it.

Comment: Ah ok, you simply put the tableView into editmode and then set editable on your UITextView while your UITableView is in edit mode for that specific row. Then when you leave edit mode you disable editable on that textView again. You don't ever convert a cell to a textView though. Your cell simply has a UITextView in it of which you handles change based on the tableView's cellForRowAtIndex delegate method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997708/uitextview-inside-uitableview

Comment: Thank u Mark, this very helpful, it works, but the UITextView is under the cell view on edit mode, i'll try to solve this problem.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @raed If you are doing exactly the same, then you can have a condition in `-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` method, that if the tableview is in edit mode return YES else execute that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default edit button to you navigationItem barbutton inside viewDidLoad as shown below.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

As give in the apple document

> editButtonItem - Returns a bar button item that toggles its title and associated state between Edit and Done. The default button action invokes the setEditing:animated: method.

Override setEditing:animated: in your view controller as shown below.

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
      [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

You can make use of bool variable **editing** to achieve your requirements.

Comment: It very helpful from you, thank you very much, now i can switch to Edit mode, but i still don't know how to show the information presented in UITableView to UITextView just like :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/EnablingEditModeinaViewController/EnablingEditModeinaViewController.html