# Forward taps from UITextView to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I've got a UITextView in a uitableviewcell that I am using exclusively to allow copy/paste of the contents. However, single taps to the textView are not getting forwarded to the tableViewCell.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You could add a tap gesture to call a method that invokes `selectRowAtIndexPath:` from within the `UITableViewCell` subclass. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997708/uitextview-inside-uitableview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
- (void)textTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // Get the text view from gesture recognizer or some delegate method
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;

    UIView *cellToBeSelected = textView.superview;

    // Try to get the correct cell view according to received view hierarchical.
    while (![cellToBeSelected isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
    {
        cellToBeSelected = [cellToBeSelected superview];
    }

    // Select the cell
    if (cellToBeSelected)
    {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cellToBeSelected]
                                    animated:YES
                              scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```